# convert date to UTC with +00

Tags: java, simpledateformat

How can I convert Date to format "2015-10-26 20:07:45+00"

If I use UTC-"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'", I am getting "2015-10-26T20:07:45Z"

Should I simply replace T with space and Z with +00, or any other format can I use to get the format I wanted directly?

```
TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC");
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
df.setTimeZone(tz);
String nowAsISO = df.format(now);
```

Comment: what is your input? what is now?

Comment: Did you check the [documentation of SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for an answer?

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation of `SimpleDateFormat`, there is no pattern symbol which displays the ISO-UTC-offset as "+00". The closest pattern symbol would be "X" which displays the hour offset only if the timezone offset deviates from UTC. So I see mainly two options:

```
TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC");
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'+00'");
df.setTimeZone(tz);
String nowAsISO = df.format(new Date());
System.out.println(nowAsISO);
```

Setting the literal offset is still okay here (exceptionally) because you explicitly set the timezone UTC on the format object. But it is still a hack.

Otherwise you can use (if on [Java 8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) - using the new pattern symbol "x"):

```
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssx");
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC);
String nowAsISO = dtf.format(zdt);
System.out.println(nowAsISO); // 2015-10-27 18:13:15+00
```

Alternative - and IMHO better - way in Java-8:

```
DateTimeFormatter dtf = 
  DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssx").withZone(ZoneOffset.UTC);
Instant now = new Date().toInstant(); // or better: Instant.now();
String nowAsISO = dtf.format(now);
System.out.println(nowAsISO); // 2015-10-27 18:13:15+00
```

Answer (score 0):

DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssz");